# Windows scheduler : will same process instances concurrently run across different Tasks?

Tags: windows, scheduled-task

I have configured Windows Scheduler to not run many instances of my application :
[image]

But i am not sure about how windows will detect many instance. I mean i have an executable that deeply change its bheaviour accordingly to command line. For that reason i have many task that will trigger the same executable with different parameters.

Will the "Do not start new instance" of one task scheduler block execution, if another instance of same program is running due to another task scheduling (with different parameters)?

What i mean is :

```
Task 1 -> program.exe some_param      -> Do not start new instance
Taks 2 -> program.exe different_param -> Do not start new instance
```

What happened if Task 2 try to start while Task 1 is running? Is Windows smart enought to understand that due to the different task and parameters they should not interfer, or second Task will wait Task 1 complention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That setting does not have any affect on other tasks. So Task 1 and Task 2 will run concurrently regardless of the setting. The setting prevents running *the same* task concurrently. For example, if a task runs hourly, and a new instance is to be launched but the previous instance has not finished, it will not launch a new instance.

Comment: Good, for one moment i was afraid that Windows will use process name to looking for previous instance. Glad to hear that my concern was futile, thanks